# How get generated deployment bucket name in serverless?

Tags: amazon-s3, serverless-framework

By default, Serverless creates a bucket with a generated name like `<service name>-serverlessdeploymentbuck-1x6jug5lzfnl7` to store your service's stack state. But how can I get this name inside serverless.yml?

**Important**

using `provider.deploymentBucket.name` is not en option because it where you set this name not where you can get it especially when it generated by serverless itself.

Comment: Have you tried using `!Ref ServerlessDeploymentBucket`? Not 100% sure whether this resource is created in the same stack.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `!Ref ServerlessDeploymentBucket`. It's created as part of the rest of your application stack, so you can reference it within the template.

More information is available [here](https://serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/guide/serverless.yml/)